# How to call jquery function from ActionLink asp.net Mvc 3?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

How to call jquery function from actionlink. My this.href result : 
"localhost:54678/Customer?param=1" but i need this.href:
"localhost:54678/Customer/EditCustomer/?param=1"
Customer is Controller and EditCustomer is Action.

Jquery:

```
  $('#mylink').click(function (e) {
            jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open');
            var iframe = $('#frame');
            alert(this.href);
            $(iframe).attr('src', this.href);

            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

View:

```
  <%= Html.ActionLink(
             "Click",
             "Index",
    new { param = 1 },
    new { id = "mylink" })
%>
```

localhost:54678/Customer/EditCustomer/?param=1  how to call this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<%= Html.ActionLink( 
         "Click", 
         "EditCustomer",
new { param = 1 }, 
new { id = "mylink" })
```

%>

Answer (score 0):

Your ActionLink is pointing to the Index action of the Customer controller.  Change it to the EditCustomer like so:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
             "Click",
             "EditCustomer",
    new { param = 1 },
    new { id = "mylink" })
%>
```